# Nginx - не могу получить доступ к серверу по IP [Ubuntu 16.04]

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, сервер, gunicorn

Подключил Nginx на сервере, запустил его, вот site-enabled файл:

```
    server {
            listen 80;
            location / {
                    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
                    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            }
    }
```

Делаю переадресацию на localhost, потому что использую Gunicorn для flask.

Пытаюсь сделать запрос по IP с другого компьютера, ответа нет. Если я использую `curl x.x.x.x` с самого сервера на самого себя, то мне выдается `отказано в доступе`.

Что может быть не так?

Comment: Вопрос, вероятно, будет закрыт, так как на Stack Overflow на русском вопросы принято задавать только на русском языке. Пожалуйста, переведите ваш вопрос на русский язык или воспользуйтесь Stack Overflow на английском.

Comment: а `http://127.0.0.1:8000` функционирует нормально? тогда смотрите логи nginx-а.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin localhost функционирует нормально, фласк отвечает. А что именно в логах смотреть?

Comment: Смотрите настройки файрвола

Comment: Ну и как обычно, nginx перезапускали? Что пишет `nginx -t`?